# Primality testing using Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, counterexamples, elementary-proofs

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the claim given below?

Inspired by an alternative definition of the Frobenius primality test which is given in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.7920.pdf) I have formulated the following claim:

> Let $n$ be an odd natural number that is not a perfect square and let $c$ be the smallest odd prime number such that $\left(\frac{c}{n}\right)=-1$ , where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes a Jacobi symbol . Let $T_m(x)$ be the mth Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind , then $n$ is prime iff $T_n\left(1+\sqrt{c}\right) \equiv 1- \sqrt{c} \pmod{n}$ .

The test runs in polynomial time , you can try it [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjtGKwyAQRd_9ipJ90ewEOilsWWQ-Yb8gpCDGghQ1VQsppf32mmR36UNfBrzjnHs-mKf2C7f4vd9JNjmVuQclqGtrBQ1KhG1f_4SBI3ghWRiGMVpnuBd0O4a4PjTtIASwR36KwRt9MpHr8p-oQYgmX6LnWggh7yydY9brcqZOsMxD28xRKXBXm34bZo2bu_Jp3NDm3-zg604B9g8hp7FreyKOzUp9kVtgd1aMbErni4pLWLY-80oHN4Zks6nE7PxaiZ9vUUT4d7zE1TtWaXwCuYNq6A==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). I have verified this claim for $n$ up to $10^{10}$ .

The Android app that implements this test can be found on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.primuslab.primalitytest).

Comment: But $\left(\frac cn\right)$ is $-1$ means that $c$ is not a square $\mod n$, then what does $1-\sqrt c\ (\mathrm{mod}\ n)$ mean?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Please see Definition  1.1. in the linked paper.

Comment: I see, thanks. Still I am not sure how to make this rigorous. Is it equality in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z[t]/(t^2-c)$ or something?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't know.

Comment: I believe the relevant place in your code is `Mod(x,Mod(x^2-c,n))`. Does this (for Sage) mean what I wrote? I guess so but I am not sure.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You are right.

Comment: "only if" is certainly true, following from the congruence $T_p(x) \equiv x^p \mod p$ for $p$ an odd prime. For "if" I have no clue, but in the most naive possible random model ( $T_n(1+\sqrt{c} )$ is a random element in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{c}]/n$ for $n$ composite) it has a probability $1/n^2$ of failure for each $n$, hence based on your data we expect it is true for all $n$.